# System NOT running to use fully qualified hostnames

Tags: couchdb

Related to:

- [How to verify a CouchDB 2.0 cluster setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539427/how-to-verify-a-couchdb-2-0-cluster-setup)
- http://stackoverflow.com/a/42503412/1269466
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298919/setup-couchdb-2-0-cluster

I'd like to setup a cluster with CouchDB 2.0.0, but first I need a single host running well. I have tried MANY hostname configurations but they always result in:

```
** System NOT running to use fully qualified hostnames **
```

This is what I have tried, a full re-installation and reboot after each try.

```
-sname couchdb@thiscomputer.local
-sname couchdb@thiscomputer
-sname couchdb@192.168.178.59
-sname thiscomputer

-name couchdb@thiscomputer.local
-name couchdb@thiscomputer
-name couchdb@192.168.178.59
-name thiscomputer
```

These all fail. So maybe I did something wrong in the server configuration?

**hostname**

```
pi@thiscomputer:~ $ sudo cat /etc/hostname 
thiscomputer
```

**hosts**

```
pi@thiscomputer:~ $ sudo cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   thiscomputer    thiscomputer.local
::1         localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1   localhost
```

Comment: Have you try to bind your CouchDB to 0.0.0.0? I have seen in the maillist that CouchDB cluster setup had some problems for singlenode configuration with 127.0.0.0

Comment: yes I set the bind to 0.0.0.0 in local.ini

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Support on GitHub here: https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/729#issuecomment-319202529 helped me solve the issue.

Lessons learned:

- Never use -sname. We will be removing this suggestion from the sample
  vm.args file.
- If this is a single node, not a cluster, always use
  -name couchdb@127.0.0.1.
- If DNS isn't configured, use IP addresses only: -name couchdb@192.168.0.1.
- If DNS is configured, use the FQDN
  only: -name couchdb@my.host.name.com
- Tricks with /etc/hosts don't
  work as Erlang bypasses libresolv.

Credits, kudo's and free beer for the wisdom above should go to [Wohali](https://github.com/wohali)